# How does Magento 2 ACL works

Tags: magento2, acl

I know how to setup ACL for my module. I also know this method is responsible for ACL:

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed(static::ADMIN_RESOURCE);
}
```

I want to know the real mechanism behind the ACL methods in Magento 2.

Does Magento hit the database tables (`authorization_rule` and `authorization_role`) every time the admin controller is invoked? (I believe it doesn't).

If it doesn't then how is this handled?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why this was the case, but I found that using:

`Magento\Company\Api\AuthorizationInterface`

..rather than..

`Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface`

yielded the correct ACL check result from within in an Adapter class that I was working on. The latter may require the context, I'm not entirely sure why it was always returning false for me.

Answer (score 0):

> **Magento 2 authorization system**

1. The `acl.xml` is declaring resources used for backend actions protection and web API. It means, authorization system is now unified
2. Resulting merged `acl.xml` is used to build 2 identical ACL trees for managing permissions in the admin panel. One is on the admin user role edit page, another is on web API integration edit page
3. Permissions are checked in `\Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction::_isAllowed` when accessing admin panel pages (this method is almost always overridden in child controllers to perform check against custom resource). During web API calls processing this check is done by framework based on
   `resources` node declared in [webapi.xml](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication.html)
4. See any core `acl.xml` to understand the syntax, e.g. [customer module acl.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Customer/etc/acl.xml). Also Magento 2 has XSDs available for all configs, so if [configured properly](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-urn.html), IDE should verify and suggest correct syntax on the fly
5. To check if current user (admin or web API) has permission to access particular resource declared in `acl.xml`, just use `\Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface::isAllowed($resource)`. User context is identified automatically in this case

**Update**

> **Programmatically Checking ACL Rules**

> Magento provides an abstract type, Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface, which a client programmer (you!) can use to validate the currently logged in user against a specific access control rule. i.e., if you were playing fast and loose with Magento’s Don’t use the Object Manager guidelines, the following

```
$auth = $object_manger->get('Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface');
if($auth->isAllowed('Pulsestorm_AclExample::config')) {
    //user is logged in here
} else {
    //user is not logged in here
}
```

> would check if the currently logged in user was assigned our Pulsestorm_AclExample::config rule. If you’re not playing fast and loose with Magento’s Don’t use the Object Manager guidelines, you can inject the auth checking object with something like this

```
public function __construct(Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface $auth)
{
    $this->authorization = $auth;
}
```

> If you’re in a controller that extends the \Magento\Backend\App\Action controller, you automatically have access to the authorization checking object via the _authorization property.

```
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected function someControllerMethod()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('VendoreName_ModuleName::vendoreName_moduleNameadmin_index_index');
    }

}
```

> Regarding the controller method above — if you’re injecting additional arguments via the __construct method, don’t forget to include the admin context object (Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context). This context object is where the auth checking object is, itself, instantiated and injected.

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;        
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    //...
}
```

> Finally, for the curious, in a stock Magento install (circa spring 2016), the Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface object type resolves to a Magento\Framework\Authorization object. The class for this object is found here

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/Authorization.php
```

[For More Click here](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_access_control_list_rules/)

Comment: Yeah, this is what I have been doing. But my qst is does Magento `Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface::isAllowed()` hits the database on every admin controller invoke? Certainly, Magento saves the permissions on the database. How is this dealt with?

Comment: You are define many resources in magento. like Menu.xml, system.xml, etc. so you need to allow only some resource to limited user. Now resources are define but how and when use, that time you use  Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface::isAllowed() function in diffrent files..