# Magento 2.4 Admin Custom Controller Check If User Logged In and Redirect to Login If Not

Tags: admin, magento2.4, login, admin-controller, authentication

In an Admin Controller Class, How do I check if the admin user is logged in, then redirect to the login page if not logged in, then return to the previous controller after login?

A cut down version of my script as follows.

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;

class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface

{
    /* Constructor */
  
    public function execute(): Page|Redirect
    {
        if (!$this->_isAllowed()) {
            ### How and where to redirect here? ###
        }

        /* Do stuff here and load Index page */
    }
}
```

Not sure if "$this->_isAllowed()" is the correct method to use to check if an admin user is logged in?

Not sure where/how to redirect if user not logged in, or session has ended.

Advice on the correct Magento way to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: When your this custom controller called?

Answer (score 0):

> **In Magento 2, admins can only access pages after a successful login. The page access for admins is configured in the acl.xml file.**

ACL.XML : https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/backend/create-access-control-list-rule/

**Method - 1 : You can restrict admin user access by using a constant variable**

```
const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Vendor_MyModule::create'
```

**Method - 2 : You can restrict admin user access by using the method below in your controller.**

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
 return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_MyModule::create');
}
```

*For more information, please check the following URLs.*

1. https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-acl-access-control-lists.html#step-3-check-acl-rule
2. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/320580/82670